# Склонировал репозиторий, в "git log" добавился "origin/HEAD", что это?

Tags: git, tortoise-git

Есть два удалённых репозитория, которые были получены мной на локальную машину двумя разными способами. Первый (как я делал всегда) - создал каталог, инициализировал там пустой репозиторий, в настройках задал удалённый урл (ssh), далее fetch & pull. Второй (решил немного ускорить процесс) - создал каталог, и далее просто склонировал в него репозиторий. В обоих случаях результат достигнут, но при открытии истории в tortoise git меня смутил лишний значок во втором варианте, я раньше не видел такого: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
git branch -a показывает соответственно для первого и второго:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что это и не возникнет ли в дальнейшем проблем?

Comment: Так и должно быть. HEAD указывает, какая ветка у вас сейчас активна. Нужно больше волноваться, почему в первом HEAD отсутствует ;)

Comment: Да вроде никогда проблем с пушами не было...